# ROS Webcam Stream Really Slow

Tags: camera, raspicam, streaming-video, picamera

I am trying to stream the images from my camera to a laptop via ROS. Here is my setup:

- Raspberry Pi 3B+ with USB Webcam. It is running ROS Noetic with `usb_camera_node`
- An Ubuntu 20.04.1 laptop with ROS Noetic. I am reviewing the live stream using `rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view`

When I tried this, the stream is really laggy and slow. I am barely getting 10 fps. I was able to do camera calibration with it but mapping with it will be really challenging. I have also tried `cv_camera` and `raspicam_node` and I got a huge performance boost from `raspicam_node` but it still lags. Is there any way to speed it up. I also tried decreasing the video quality with no luck. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Not really a Pi related question, I see someone else already tried to bump you here, which I think was a mistake. Have you looked at the ROS docs related to cv_camera_node  http://wiki.ros.org/cv_camera there are parameters that allow setting the framerate (but default is higher then what you are getting) as well as setting the size of the image which may help improve your framerate.

Comment: Looks useful. How can you set parameters in ROS?

Comment: That would also be documented on the ROS site

Comment: Does this software officially support Raspberry Pi (and Pi 3 particularly), or are you experimenting? Are you sure it is supposed to run faster than 10 FPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ROS node `usb_cam` should be publishing a `/usb_cam/image/compressed`. What you can do is since the compressed video is much faster(roughly 20fps), you can convert the compressed image to a raw image on your much more powerful VM or laptop. Here is the ROS command you should run on your laptop: `rosrun image_transport republish raw in:=/usb_cam/image_raw  compressed out:=/converted/image_raw`

**PLEASE NOTE:** Don't add compressed in front of `/usb_cam/image_raw` even though that is the actual topic. The topic `/usb_cam/image_raw` is the base for the image formats. The republished likes it in the base format and you can specify the format you want to convert to before `in:=` or `out:=`.